# Android Source: What is building exactly and is it necessary to test small changes?

Tags: android, build

For a project, I am changing certain ContentProvider-files in the Application Framework Layer of the Android System. As I am trying different things, I was wondering if it is necessary to build the Android Source for every change I make, or if there is a way to somehow emulate the system without the build? 
I am not entirely sure what "building" means, as I cannot find a proper definition including Android as a context. I assume it is some kind of compiling?
Converting the source code into an executable program? In that case I do not think there is another way, is there?
But do I understand building correct in the first place? In that case, I would believe there is no other way than building the system every time and then see how it works out.
So I might have the solution right here, but I was hoping someone could assure me that it is right or maybe tell me why it is not?!
Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Building*** in this context means that all Android source files are re-compiled by the java compiler and a massive `.jar` file is produced. This is the `Android.jar` file that we see in the library dependencies of an Android application project.

Unfortunately, the short answer is that there is no way out for you except to re-compile the entire blob of the Android framework files each time you make a change. What I can advise you is to plan all your changes beforehand so you don't end up wasting a lot of time.